# JS couldn't localize function in the same object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following js file:

```
function RequestHandler(marker) {
this.marker = marker;


this.getDate = function () {
    var currentdate = new Date();

    var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/" + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1)
        + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear() + "  "
        + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
        + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();

    return datetime;
}

this.registerEventHandlers = function () {
    $('[data-send-event]').on('click', function () {
         requestData = {
            Timestamp: this.getDate(),
            EventType: 0,
            Latitude: marker.getPosition().lat(),
            Longitude: marker.getPosition().lng()
         }

    });
}
```

And when js fire `$('[data-send-event]').on('click')` it gives me error that it can't locate `this.getDate()`. Could anyone helps me please?

Comment: That's a much better answer than the one I gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of this inside that function is incorrect. You can do several things:

Bind the scope to the function

```
this.registerEventHandlers = function () {
        $('[data-send-event]').on('click', (function () {
             requestData = {
                Timestamp: this.getDate(),
                EventType: 0,
                Latitude: marker.getPosition().lat(),
                Longitude: marker.getPosition().lng()
             }

        }).bind(this));
    }
```

Save the scope in a variable an access it

```
this.registerEventHandlers = function () {
    var that = this;
    $('[data-send-event]').on('click', function () {
         requestData = {
            Timestamp: that.getDate(),
            EventType: 0,
            Latitude: marker.getPosition().lat(),
            Longitude: marker.getPosition().lng()
         }

    });
}
```

Use an arrow function:

```
this.registerEventHandlers = function () {
        $('[data-send-event]').on('click', () => {
             requestData = {
                Timestamp: this.getDate(),
                EventType: 0,
                Latitude: marker.getPosition().lat(),
                Longitude: marker.getPosition().lng()
             }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Rather than posting an answer for a duplicate question, vote to close for the duplicate.  This is already covered.

Comment: Yes indeed, it would have saved me time :)